# Maven build issue with Java 1.4 and Maven 2.1.0

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, java1.4

I have a decade-old Java source code (1.4) and looking now to run the application using Maven. I configured supported Maven 2.1.0 for Java 1.4 version. But when run the Maven build, got the below error.

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/codehaus/plexus/classworlds/launcher/Launcher (Unsupported major.minor version 50.0)

[image]

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Upgrade to java 1.8 and use the latest maven. Source written with Java 1.4 still should compile and run under 1.8

Comment: @locus2k:- I compiled with java 1.8 with maven 3.6 and trying to build jar using maven, but the same error repeats.

Comment: are you running the maven commands via command lines? and if you are what java is on your home path (`java -version`)

Comment: java version "1.8.0_74" and running maven through eclipse

Comment: 50.0 is java 1.6 it could be that an older library is trying to call a new library.

Comment: Please run Maven with the recent Java version and report the command line output in the question. I don't understand where this popup window comes from (as Maven is purely a command line tool).